# How do I use extern to make an array of structs accessible from another file?

Tags: c, global-variables, extern

I have an array of structs in a file called global.c defined as so that I would like to make accessible from other files.

global.c:

```
#include "global.h" 


typedef struct NameMap {
 const char *from;
 const char *to;
} NameMap; 

NameMap nameMap[] = {
  {"blah", "blah"},
  {"blah", "blah"},
  ....,
  ....,
};
```

In the file global.h, I have the line `extern NameMap nameMap[]`, however in another file (say main.c), even if I `#include "global.h"` and link properly, I am getting the error `Unknown type name NameMap` while compiling global.h.
How can I fix this? I would like to access NameMap from main.c.

Comment: Your struct needs to be in the header file.

Comment: Isn't declaring variables in a header file bad practice?

Comment: Your struct isn't a variable

Comment: For `extern NameMap nameMap[];` the size must be specified.

Comment: typedef struct ... should be in the header file global.h and not in global.c.  It's not a variable -- it's a typedef, so there should be no issue.

Comment: The size is constant, so that shouldn't be an issue. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @FiddlingBits why does it have to be specified

Answer (score 3):

- Include the `nameMap` *declaration* in the .h header file.  The [size must be specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77189330/how-do-i-use-extern-to-make-an-array-of-structs-accessible-from-another-file/77189451#comment136077772_77189330) if ones wants an *array*.

```
typedef struct NameMap {
 const char *from;
 const char *to;
} NameMap;

#define NAMEMAP_N 5
extern NameMap nameMap[NAMEMAP_N];
```

- In the .c file with the `nameMap` *definition* add a `static_assert` to ensure consistency.

```
#include "global.h"

NameMap nameMap[] = {
  {"blah", "blah"},
  {"blah", "blah"},
  ....,
  ....,
};

#include <assert.h>
static_assert(sizeof nameMap/sizeof nameMap[0] == NAMEMAP_N, "");
```

---

To address [@0___________](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77189330/how-do-i-use-extern-to-make-an-array-of-structs-accessible-from-another-file/77189451?noredirect=1#comment136077983_77189451) concern, another approach: provide a pointer (rather than an array) and array count separately.

This is a good alternative when the size of the array is not needed as a *constant*.

*.h

```
extern NameMap *nameMap;
extern size_t nameMap_n;
```

*.c

```
static NameMap nameMap0[] = {
  {"blah", "blah"},
  {"blah", "blah"},
  ....,
  ....,
};

NameMap *nameMap = nameMap0;

size_t nameMap_n = sizeof nameMap/sizeof nameMap[0];
```

Comment: It is very inconvenient to define size. You need to change the size when you add something to the array. Also very error-prone. You add something and forget to change definition. Imagine having hundreds of similar arrays in your project.

Comment: @0___________ Yes, inconvenient - a reasonable complaint.  "You add something and forget to change definition." is mitigated by the `static_assert` to reduce errors.  What is your suggested alternative?

Comment: I real code I prefer sentinel values if possible or arrays being a part of the structs with size member

Comment: Fortunately the array of structs is guaranteed to not change size, so this approach is sufficient for my use case.

Comment: @0___________ True that a sentinel value is a reasonable alterative, as well as only having `extern NameMap *nameMap;`. Yet since OP asked for accessibility to an array of structs, changing the array or making it a pointer shift the goal.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica why size must be specified. Maybe it is an gcc extension (have no time to search the standard) but I use it all the time

Comment: @0___________ "size must be specified" if code, outside the defining .c file, needs to know the size of the array.  Depending on OP's goal, that size may be needed as a constant or variable.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica so it does not have to be specified then

Comment: @0___________ As OP's goal is "make an array of structs accessible".  That reasonable has a size need.  OP's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77189330/how-do-i-use-extern-to-make-an-array-of-structs-accessible-from-another-file/77189451?noredirect=1#comment136078063_77189451) supports this.  Many possibilities exist.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the declaration of the struct to the ***header file*** (.h) before you declare `extern` object as compiler needs to know its type.

for example in "global.h":

```
typedef struct NameMap {
 const char *from;
 const char *to;
} NameMap;

extern NameMap nameMap[];
```

Then in your C file define it and initialize. In this case I would use sentinel value:

```
#include "global.h"

NameMap nameMap[] = {
  {"blah", "blah"},
  {"blah", "blah"},
  /*
  ....,
  ....,
  */
  {NULL,NULL},
};
```

And in another ".c" file you can iterate through this array or use it another way

```
#include "global.h"

void foo(void)
{
    for(size_t index = 0; nameMap[index].from && nameMap[index].to; index++)
    {
        printf("FROM: %s TO: %s\n", nameMap[index].from, nameMap[index].to);
    }
}
```

If you want size you can wrap it into the struct

```
typedef struct NameMap {
 const char *from;
 const char *to;
} NameMap;

typedef struct 
{
    size_t size;
    NameMap *map;
}NameMapData;

extern NameMapData nameMap;
```

and

```
#define SA(a) (sizeof(a) / sizeof(*(a)))


NameMap Map[] = {
  {"blah", "blah"},
  {"blah", "blah"},
  /*
  ....,
  ....,
  */
};

NameMapData  nameMap = 
{
    SA(Map),
    Map,
};
```

Comment: In the other file, what does `printf("%zu\n", sizeof(nameMap));` report?  I get "error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'NameMap[]'"

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica it is obvious that you can't use `sizeof` in this context. I am surprised that have tried.

Comment: Yet the goal was "How do I use extern to make an array of structs accessible".  `extern NameMap nameMap[];` does not meet the _array_ access, just `nameMap` _pointer_ attributes.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica then is no possible to make an array accessible to the function without using compilation unit or global scope objects